# How to find all documents of an array of id's

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How can I find all the documents of a given array of Id's. What I wanted is something like this:

```
for (let y = 0; y < dadosORS_id.length; y++) {
    mongoClient.collection('registosORS', function(err, collection) {
      collection.find({ id: dadosORS_id[y] }).toArray(function(err, result) {

     }) 
    }) 
  }) 
}
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Remove the outer loop and just do `mongoClient.collection('registosORS', function(err, collection) {
      collection.find({ 'id': { '$in': dadosORS_id } }).toArray(function(err, result) {

     }) 
    })`

Comment: Thanks. I believe this was answered in another thread.